# Partially filter on a map to get key : Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I have a map:

`val mapTest = Map("Haley" -> Map("Deran" -> 0.4, "Mike" -> 0.3), "Jack"  -> Map("Deran" -> 0.3, "Mike" -> 0.3))`

I want to retrieve the key based on a value.  Given the value `"Deran"-> 0.4` I should get `"Haley"`.

I have tried using this:

`mapTest.filter(_._2 == Map("Deran" -> 0.4))`

but it doesn't work as filter selects all the values at a time. That's the first question. My second question is what If two keys verify that predicates such as the case for `"Jack"` and `"Haley"` for `"Mike"`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
val toSearch = List("Deran - > 0.4," Mike" -> 0.3)
mapTest.collectFirst {
  case (key, values) if (toSearch.forall { case (k, v) => values.get(k).contains(v) }) => key
}
```

Comment: I guess that can work if we already know the position to search in the map. but that is not going to work if we are iterating over elements of the map

Comment: @MunaAr what does that mean?

Comment: having the testmap of many elements (the testmap is for illustration purpose only) I want to retrieve the key for the map value containing not all the elements but some of them

Comment: @MunaAr can you please edit your question and being clear of what you want to do. Because right now or is pretty confusing. Ping me when you have it complete with examples of inputs and expected outputs and will happily edit my answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This could probably solve it:

```
def filter[K, NK, NV](m: Map[K, Map[NK, NV]])(p: ((NK, NV)) => Boolean): Vector[K] =
  m.view.collect { case (k, v) if v.exists(p) => k }.toVector
```

Where `NK` is a generic type for a **n**ested key and `NV` a generic type for a **n**ested value.

This works as follows with the following inputs and outputs

```
val in1: (String, Double) = "Deran" -> 0.4
val out1: Vector[String] = Vector("Haley")

val in2: (String, Double) = "Mike" -> 0.3
val out2: Vector[String] = Vector("Haley", "Jack")

assert(filter(mapTest)(_ == in1) == out1)
assert(filter(mapTest)(_ == in2) == out2)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/q61VvR2eTqasttTKuqpNzQ/5).

Using a predicate you can be very generic but note that the complexity grows proportionally to the size of both the map and the nested maps contained therein.

If you can be less generic and simply check for equality, you can drop the predicate and use this to your advantage to make the nested check run in constant time:

```
def filter[K, NK, NV](m: Map[K, Map[NK, NV]])(p: (NK, NV)): Vector[K] =
  m.view.collect { case (k, v) if v.get(p._1).contains(p._2) => k }.toVector

assert(filter(mapTest)(in1) == out1)
assert(filter(mapTest)(in2) == out2)
```

This variant is also available [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/q61VvR2eTqasttTKuqpNzQ/10).